# Extract the filename from a path

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I want to extract filename from below path:

```
D:\Server\User\CUST\MEA\Data\In\Files\CORRECTED\CUST_MEAFile.csv
```

Now I wrote this code to get filename. This working fine as long as the folder level didn't change. But in case the folder level has been changed, this code need to rewrite. I looking a way to make it more flexible such as the code can always extract filename regardless of the folder level.

```
($outputFile).split('\')[9].substring(0)
```

Answer (score 249, accepted):

If you are ok with including the extension this should do what you want.

```
$outputPath = "D:\Server\User\CUST\MEA\Data\In\Files\CORRECTED\CUST_MEAFile.csv"
$outputFile = Split-Path $outputPath -leaf
```

Comment: This is a great answer. It solves the problem in the most "built-in" way. However, for my needs, I needed both the filename with extension and the base filename, so I used @angularsen's answer. There's another parameter, -leafbase, but it's only supported on PowerShell Core 6+.

Answer (score 94):

Use [.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net):

`[System.IO.Path]::GetFileName("c:\foo.txt")` returns `foo.txt`.
`[System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension("c:\foo.txt")` returns `foo`

Comment: .NET FTW!! This is the best answer. Thanks 

Comment: How would I do the opposite - parent dir without filename?

Comment: @rokejulianlockhart `[System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName("c:\foo\bar.txt")` outputs `c:\foo`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getdirectoryname?view=net-7.0

Answer (score 43):

Using the *BaseName* in [Get-ChildItem](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Get-ChildItem) displays the name of the file and using *Name* displays the file name with the extension.

```
$filepath = Get-ChildItem "E:\Test\Basic-English-Grammar-1.pdf"

$filepath.BaseName
```

Output:

> Basic-English-Grammar-1

---

```
$filepath.Name
```

Output:

> Basic-English-Grammar-1.pdf

Comment: Way to go. This is a clean solution without adding extra dependencies to the solution. I may think that this would have been the accepted solution due to one less parameter on the line compared to the accepted answer. Simplicity in every detail is the way to go. You get convinced on that after working 20+ years working with code.

Answer (score 6):

```
Get-ChildItem "D:\Server\User\CUST\MEA\Data\In\Files\CORRECTED\CUST_MEAFile.csv"
|Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
```

Answer (score 6):

Find a file using a wildcard and get the filename:

```
Resolve-Path "Package.1.0.191.*.zip" | Split-Path -leaf
```

Answer (score 5):

```
$(Split-Path "D:\Server\User\CUST\MEA\Data\In\Files\CORRECTED\CUST_MEAFile.csv" -leaf)
```

Answer (score 5):

Just to complete [angularsen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35813186/extract-the-filename-from-a-path/44359435#44359435) that uses .NET.

In this code the path is stored in the `%1` argument (which is written in the registry under quote that are escaped: `\"%1\"` ). To retrieve it, we need the `$arg` (inbuilt arg). *Don't forget the quote around `$FilePath`.*

```
# Get the file path:
$FilePath = $args
Write-Host "FilePath: " $FilePath

# Get the complete file name:
$file_name_complete = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileName("$FilePath")
Write-Host "fileNameFull :" $file_name_complete

# Get file name without the extension:
$fileNameOnly = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension("$FilePath")
Write-Host "fileNameOnly :" $fileNameOnly

# Get the file extension:
$fileExtensionOnly = [System.IO.Path]::GetExtension("$FilePath")
Write-Host "fileExtensionOnly :" $fileExtensionOnly
```

Answer (score 5):

You can try this:

```
[System.IO.FileInfo]$path = "D:\Server\User\CUST\MEA\Data\In\Files\CORRECTED\CUST_MEAFile.csv"
# Returns name and extension
$path.Name
# Returns just name
$path.BaseName
```

Comment: $path.DirectoryName retuns D:\Server\User\CUST\MEA\Data\In\Files\CORRECTED

Answer (score 4):

You could get the result you want like this.

```
$file = "D:\Server\User\CUST\MEA\Data\In\Files\CORRECTED\CUST_MEAFile.csv"
$a = $file.Split("\")
$index = $a.count - 1
$a.GetValue($index)
```

If you use [Get-ChildItem](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Get-ChildItem) to get the "fullname", you could also use "name" to just get the name of the file.

Comment: Simply use the index `-1` if you're taking the array approach: `$file.Split("\")[-1]`

Comment: If we want to remove the extension what can we do?

Answer (score 2):

```
$file = Get-Item -Path "c:/foo/foobar.txt"
$file.Name
```

Works with both relative and absolute paths