# Powershell - Best way to extract last part of a string after many backslashes

Tags: string, powershell, split

If I have a path that is unpredictable but I always want the LAST part after the final backslash, how should I approach this?

For example

```
\\intra.X.net\Exploitation\X\Poste\Travail\X\X\folder\test
```

I want to output test only.

```
C:\temp\a\b\CDE\FG\HI
```

I want to output HI only.

I'm thinking counting how many backslashes then using splits, but do you have a better way to suggest?

Comment: `$String.split('\')[-1]` or `split-path -leaf "\\intra.X.net\Exploitation\X\Poste\Travail\X\X\folder\test"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract the filename from a path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35813186/extract-the-filename-from-a-path)

Comment: @LotPings thanks a lot my friend! I managed to get the Split-path working in an expression within a pipeline : 
| Select-Object Name, @{name='Folder';expression={ Split-Path $($_.Directory) -leaf } }

How would I write the split using $_.Directory though? Can't get it to work.

Comment: Depending on the type, you might have to cast to a [string] first. Or try `$_.Parent.Name`

Comment: Use `$_.DirectoryName`

Comment: @Rakha - the `.Directory` property IS ALREADY just the last dir of the path to the object. [*grin*] no need to split anything ...

Comment: Yes, if you use ().Directory you get only the names, but when you select, directory is the full path. get-childitem C:\temp -recurse | select name,directory 

z.txt                                                                        C:\temp    
dsdfsf.txt                                                                   C:\temp\zzz

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments,

You can call `.split('\')[-1]` like this:

```
$path = "\\intra.X.net\Exploitation\X\Poste\Travail\X\X\folder\test"
$last = $path.split('\')[-1] # test
```

Or you can call `split-path` with the `leaf` arg like this:

```
$path = "C:\temp\a\b\CDE\FG\HI"
$last = split-path $path -leaf # HI
```