# Remove part of the string in powershell in hashtable

Tags: powershell

I got driver list

```
$HashTable = Get-WindowsDriver –Online -All | Where-Object {$_.Driver -like "oem*.inf"} | Select-Object Driver, OriginalFileName, ClassDescription, ProviderName, Date, Version
Write-Host "All installed third-party drivers" -ForegroundColor Yellow
$HashTable | Sort-Object ClassDescription | Format-Table
```

The table displays full inf file path in a OriginalFileName column. I need to cut full path e.g.

```
C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\pantherpointsystem.inf_amd64_bde4cf569a728803\pantherpointsystem.inf
```

to

```
pantherpointsystem.inf.
```

And so that way in all lines.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract the filename from a path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35813186/extract-the-filename-from-a-path)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To split the filename from the complete path, you can use Powershells `Split-Path` cmdlet like this:

```
$FullPath = "C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\pantherpointsystem.inf_amd64_bde4cf569a728803\pantherpointsystem.inf"
$FileName = $FullPath | Split-Path -Leaf
```

or use .NET like this:

```
$FullPath = "C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\pantherpointsystem.inf_amd64_bde4cf569a728803\pantherpointsystem.inf"
$FileName = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($FullPath)
```

In your case, I'd use a calculated property to fill the Hashtable:

```
$HashTable = Get-WindowsDriver –Online -All | 
                Where-Object {$_.Driver -like "oem*.inf"} | 
                Select-Object Driver, @{Name = 'FileName'; Expression = {$_.OriginalFileName | Split-Path -Leaf}},
                              ClassDescription, ProviderName, Date, Version

Write-Host "All installed third-party drivers" -ForegroundColor Yellow
$HashTable | Sort-Object ClassDescription | Format-Table
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
$FullPath = "C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\pantherpointsystem.inf_amd64_bde4cf569a728803\pantherpointsystem.inf"
$Required = $FullPath.Split("\")[-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be a `RegEx` one:

```
$FullPath = "C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\pantherpointsystem.inf_amd64_bde4cf569a728803\pantherpointsystem.inf"
$FullPath -match '.*\\(.*)$'
$Required = $matches[1]
```

`.*\\(.*)$` matches all chars after the last dash `\` and before the end of the line `$`