# Split a Path and take out only the last part (filename) Powershell

Tags: string, powershell, parsing, split

I'm very new to powershell and im currently trying to write a script that finds a referenced filepath in a file, takes out only the last part of the path (The filename) and moves it to the same destination like the folder containing it.

I have a functional script that does what i want, the only thing left is that its not supposed to look for the whole path of the referenced file. 
Because the path isnt correct anymore.
It should just look for the filename and find and move it.

This is my current script:

```
    $source      = 'Z:\Documents\16_Med._App\Aufträge\RuheEKG_24HBP_Skript\Ursprung_test'
$destination = 'Z:\Documents\16_Med._App\Aufträge\RuheEKG_24HBP_Skript\24BHD'
$toDelete    = 'Z:\Documents\16_Med._App\Aufträge\RuheEKG_24HBP_Skript\ToDelete'
$pattern1    = 'AmbulatoryBloodPressure'
$pattern2    = 'RuheEKG'


# Erstellt Array mit pfad und filename
$allFiles = @(Get-ChildItem $source -File | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName)

foreach($file in $allFiles) {
    # Dateinhalt als Array
    $content = Get-Content -Path $file

    # Wählt Destinationspfad
        if ($content | Select-String -Pattern $pattern1 -SimpleMatch -Quiet)  
         {
        $dest = $destination
    }
    else {
        $dest = $toDelete
    }

    # Prüft ob Datei einen Pfad enthält
    $refCount = 0
    $content | Select-String -Pattern '(^.*)([A-Z]:\\.+$)' -AllMatches | ForEach-Object {


        $prefix  = $_.Matches[0].Groups[1].Value   
        $refPath = $_.Matches[0].Groups[2].Value   # Bitmap file Path wird geholt

        if (Test-Path -Path $refPath -PathType Leaf) {
            Write-Host "Moving referenced file '$refPath' to '$dest'"
            Move-Item -Path $refPath -Destination $dest -Force


        }
        else {
            Write-Warning "Referenced file '$refPath' not found"
        }
    }
    $refPath -split "\"
       $refPath[4]
    write-host $refpath

    # Bewegt die Files an die vorher festgelegte Destination.
    Write-Host "Moving file '$file' to '$dest'"
    Move-Item -Path $file -Destination $dest -Force
}
```

This is the referenced bitmap file:
[image]

Comment: Your regex doesn't seem right (^.*) will match any line that starts with an unlimited amount of any character... BTW I would rather not convert the pathes of `$allFiles` to string that early. If you keep the pathes as path objects you can use its members like `.FullName` and `.DirectoryName` later more easily.

Comment: How about `[A-Za-z]:(\\[\w\s-]*)+(\.\w{3})` as regex for the path? You dont need to care for the numbers in the beginning of the row.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extract the filename from a path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35813186/extract-the-filename-from-a-path)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have several options to *savely* work with file-paths and -names in PowerShell.

**Built-in cmdlets**

```
# Get the file name
$fileName = Split-Path $refPath -Leaf

# Get the directory path
$dirPath = Split-Path $refPath -Parent
```

**.NET methods**

```
# Get the file name
$fileName = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($refPath)

# Get the directory path
$dirPath = [System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($refPath)
```

If you want to look for the filename in another directory, you can build a new path like this:

```
# built-in version
$otherPath = Join-Path $otherDir $fileName

# .NET version
$otherPath = [System.IO.Path]::Combine($otherDir, $fileName)
```

Answer (score 4):

To get the filename of the file you want to move, use the `Split-Path` as marsze suggests.

```
$FileName = Split-Path $refPath -Leaf
```

To locate the file use `Get-ChildItem`. (`$SearchBase` is the path where you want to search)

```
$FileLocation = (Get-ChildItem -Path $SearchBase -Filter $filename -Recurse -File).FullName
```

Now to move the file use `Move-Item` and again use `Split-Path` to find the destination.

```
Move-Item -Path $FileLocation -Destination $(Split-Path $file -Parent)
```

Comment: He is searching a text for a filepath. The path changed, but the file is somewhere. So he wants to move the file to the position of the text-file. So yes, I assume the location of that text-file exists.