# How to cut specific string?

Tags: powershell

I have a string with different length. I want to cut a specific word in my string. 
Please help, I am new to PowerShell.

I tried this code, it's still not what I need.

```
$String = "C:\Users\XX\Documents\Data.txt"
$Cut = $String.Substring(22,0)
$Cut
```

My expectation is that I can return the word `Data`.

Comment: `$Cut = $String.Substring(22,4)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract the filename from a path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35813186/extract-the-filename-from-a-path)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the string is always the same format (i.e. a path ending in a filename), then there are quite a few ways to do this, such as using regular expressions.  Here is a slightly less conventional method:

```
# Define the path
$filepath = "C:\Users\XX\Documents\Data.txt"

# Create a dummy fileinfo object
$fileInfo = [System.IO.FileInfo]$filePath

# Get the file name property
$fileInfo.BaseName
```

Of course, you could do all of this in one step:

```
([System.IO.FileInfo]"C:\Users\XX\Documents\Data.txt").BaseName
```

Comment: Regular expression is not meant for this. There is a C# method [Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension) for that.

Comment: _"Regular expression is not meant for this"_  @Bakudan, what are regular expressions meant for?

Comment: The point is there are functions intended exactly for file paths. Regex is better for text processing. As per [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Uses)  "Common applications include data validation, data scraping (especially web scraping), data wrangling, simple parsing, the production of syntax highlighting systems, and many other tasks."

Comment: _"Regex is better for text processing"_ @Bakudan I am fully aware that [RegEx isn't always the best tool for the job](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/).  That's probably why I didn't actually advocated it, only mentioning it as one of many possibilities (cf. the other answers to this question).  The main intention of my answer was to show a different approach for the questioner to consider - much like you give one approach in an actual answer, and another here in the comments.

Answer (score 2):

If the path is an existing one, you could use

```
(Get-Item $String).BaseName
```

Otherwise

```
(Split-Path $String -Leaf) -Replace '\.[^\.]*$'
```

Answer (score 1):

While in that specific example the simplest way is to use `Substring(startPosition,length)` to extract file name you'd probably want to use something like this:

```
(("C:\Users\XX\Documents\Data.txt".split("\\"))[-1].Split("."))[0]
```

#### Explanation:

```
("C:\Users\XX\Documents\Data.txt".split("\\"))[-1]
```

that part split the path by `\` and returns last item (escaping it seems to be not mandatory by the way so you can use `.split("\")` instead of `.split("\\")`). From it you receive `Data.txt` so you have to separate name and extension. You can do this by splitting by `.` and choosing first element returned

Answer (score 1):

There are number of ways of doing it depending upon your input -

### Method 1 - Hard-coding using the sub-string function.

```
$String = "C:\Users\XX\Documents\Data.txt"
$Cut = $String.Substring(22,4)
$Cut
```

The above approach will work for a single input but will become difficult to manage for multiple inputs of different lengths.

### Method 2 - Using the `split` method

```
$String = "C:\Users\XX\Documents\Data.txt"
$cut = $String.Split("\")[-1].split(".")[0]
$cut
```

`Split` method will split string into substring. The index `[-1]` will return the last value returned by the `split` method. 
The second split is to return the word `Data` from the word `Data.txt`.

### Method 3 - If the input is a file path

```
$string = Get-ChildItem $env:USERPROFILE\Desktop -File | select -First 1
$Cut = $String.BaseName
```

More about method 3 [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5878/getting-started-with-powershell-file-properties-and-methods/).

Answer (score 1):

If you can use [Powershell 6 - SplitPath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/split-path?view=powershell-6#parameters)

```
#Requires -Version 6.0
Split-Path $String -LeafBase
```