# Remove text before and including third / character in a string

Tags: powershell

I have the following string result: `refs/pull/137/merge`. How do I remove the `refs/pull/137/` part so I only have `merge` left?

Comment: As @VivekKumarSingh pointed out, this has been asked before. Please either use that link or update your question to include why your question is different from the link and make sure to include what you have already tried and what is failing

Comment: Valid point. But the linked answer is about file paths. This is not a file path. Just a string.

Comment: Similar mechanism might be used, but that example is quite different from the linked one (e.g. you don't need to worry about extension).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56523796/how-to-cut-specific-string/56524054#56524054

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like with Your exact string:

```
"refs/pull/137/merge" -replace "refs/pull/137/" ""
```

But I assume the digits part used to change over time, so it's recommended to do it like:

```
"refs/pull/137/merge" -replace "refs/pull/\d+/" ""
```

But a more better solution might be `split()`ing the string and accessing its' last element, like:

```
"refs/pull/137/merge".split('/')[-1]
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply split by `/` and choose last element:

```
'refs/pull/137/merge'.split('/')[-1]
```

Answer (score 1):

since your string *resembles* a path fairly well, you can use the cmdlet designed for that. [*grin*]

```
Split-Path -Path 'refs/pull/137/merge' -Leaf
```

output = `merge`

if that doesn't suit your needs, then you will need to define your needs with a bit more detail.