# How do I get a file path without filename in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell-2.0

I have `C:\Temp\MyFolder\mytextfile.txt` in a variable called `$file`

I want `C:\Temp\MyFolder\` in another variable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extract the filename from a path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35813186/extract-the-filename-from-a-path)

Answer (score 6):

This is quite simple
You can use this piece of code to do it:

- If you want to extract file path from your $file variable :

  ```
  $file = 'C:\Temp\MyFolder\mytextfile.txt'

  $myFilePath = Split-Path $file -Parent

  $myFilePath = $myFilePath+'\'

  Write-Host $myFilePath
  ```
- If you want to extract only file name then,

  ```
  $file = 'C:\Temp\MyFolder\mytextfile.txt'

  $myFileName = Split-Path $file -leaf

  Write-Host $myFileName
  ```

I know this is a old question but still,
If you find this answer helpful please mark this as accepted, Thank you Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

see [Extract the filename from a path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35813186/extract-the-filename-from-a-path/35813307)

You could have found this using:

```
   $file.psobject.properties
```

or

```
   $file | get-member -membertype properties
```

you can obtain your result in different forms there:

```
   $file.PSParentPath
   $file.Directory
   $file.DirectoryName
```

or using

```
   $file | Select-object DirectoryName
```

or

```
   $file | select DirectoryName
```

(you can add -ExpandProperties to these before DirectoryName to have an output as base property type which is String here)